# Store the count from multiple files group by id into a separate dataframe, scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a set of 8 files and i want to get the count based on group by of a certain column and i want to store the result of each count based on id in a separate dataframe

```
PartitionFileList.par.foreach(fileName => {

      val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", true) // Use first line of all files as header
        .option("delimiter", TILDE)
        .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
        .load(fileName._2)

      val aGrpCountsIds = df.groupBy("agrpid").count()
```

}

Each of the file has the agrpid column

so at the end of of this loop i want another dataframe to look like this how do i achieve this

```
agrpid loccount propertycount det1count det2count
   1            10      20          0       30
   2            20      12          9       12      
   3            23      2           2       3
```

Each count represents a count from the file group by agrpid . Thank you

Comment: Where should these `loccount propertycount det1count det2count` columns come from?

Comment: ITs the result of group by count, aGrpCountIds will be a dataframe with the individual count and this needs to be added to main dataframe.

Comment: I think I know solution if you provide actual columns of dataframe, not the way you want it to be.